# How to fix broken file ownership and permissions

Tags: 12.04, permissions, ext4, ownership

Since LDAP is used for authentication local user Jenkins was deleted 
and this happened to one of the owned folders.
Filesystem is ext4 kernel version 3.2.0-84-generic

[image]

Comment: can you just change ownership with with chown??

Comment: Do you a backup of the files with the right permissions?

Comment: chmod does not work, no backup available.

Comment: I think you will have to relink Dropbox again

Answer (score 0):

Without a backup of your files (or some version of the files that contains the right permissions), you cannot batch restore permissions as they were exactly.

If you have the files on DropBox, simply remove your folder and resync them. But please: back them up first.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the result of a NFS mount and you try access with root. Please change to another user and check with "ls -la" again if you can see more information then "?" on the directory.

Another option would be that the problem is a result of using ACL. Please check with "getfacl dropbox". You can use "setfacl -m u:jenkins:rwx dropbox" to set the permissions back.